# How to add mysqldump config flags while using Workbench?

Tags: mysql, ssh, mysql-workbench

I am trying to export a database which is protected by a SSH key and a private network,  meaning I can't login to the host itself to run mysqldump locally and somehow the ssh -i "key" doesn't work for me to run it remotely too.

The only option I see is to connect via Workbench and dumpt it from there, but when I try to dump, I get a PROCESS privelage error. As I researched it can be circumvented by using a --no-tablespaces flag on mysqldump.exe, so I am looking for a way to add it so that Workbench would call mysqldump.exe with that flag.

I found that MySQL can read configuration files my.cnf and my.ini, but I don't know what to write in them for a --no-tablespaces alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "[MySQL Programs  /  Using MySQL Programs  /  Specifying Program Options  /  Using Option Files](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html)" page includes:

> Most MySQL programs can read startup options from option files (sometimes called configuration files). Option files provide a convenient way to specify commonly used options so that they need not be entered on the command line each time you run a program.
>
> To determine whether a program reads option files, invoke it with the `--help` option. (For `mysqld`, use `--verbose` and `--help`.) If the program reads option files, the help message indicates which files it looks for and which option groups it recognizes.

In the [syntax section](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/option-files.html#sa95628594), you can see a `[mysqldump]` header.

So check if adding the header+option to your `my.cnf` or `my.ini` would be enough:

```cs
[mysqldump]
no-tablespaces
```

---

> It complained that I need Reload permission which I couldn't find any way to get around, I don't have access to grant any privileges.

If you do not have the necessary privileges and cannot grant them to your user, you are a bit limited in what you can do. However, you can try exporting the database in a different manner that does not require the privileges you lack.

One approach is to use the `mysqldump` command-line utility, but selectively dump the data and structure of the database without trying to dump any additional information that requires higher privileges.

For example:

```bash
mysqldump -u yourUsername -p --no-tablespaces --skip-triggers --routines --events --compact yourDatabaseName > yourDatabaseName.sql
```

Be aware that by using these options, you might not get a full-fidelity dump of your database (e.g., it might not include triggers).

If you absolutely must use MySQL Workbench and are facing issues with privileges, you might need to contact the database administrator to grant you the required privileges or ask them to perform the dump for you.

Comment: thank you, this really helped to add flags, although with my particular scenario it wasn't enough - need more permissions it seems

Comment: @MovsarBekaev Did you find those permissions? Where to set them?

Comment: no, it complained that I need Reload permission which I couldn't find any way to get around, so I decided not to pursue this further. I don't have access to grant any privileges

Comment: @MovsarBekaev OK. I have edited the answer with an alternative approach, more a workaround than an actual solution.

Answer (score 0):

Abandon Workbench (since it seems to be in the way).

- From a commandline prompt, use `mysqldump` directly.
- Try ssl from the other machine (with the suitable flag to reverse the direction).  If neither direction works, elaborate on what complaint it provides.
- What version of MySQL?

> mysqldump requires at least the SELECT privilege for dumped tables, SHOW VIEW for dumped views, TRIGGER for dumped triggers, LOCK TABLES if the --single-transaction option is not used, PROCESS (as of MySQL 8.0.21) if the --no-tablespaces option is not used, and (as of MySQL 8.0.32) the RELOAD or FLUSH_TABLES priviledge with --single-transaction if both gtid_mode=ON and --set-gtid=purged=ON|AUTO.

Comment: as I wrote initially, trying to run mysqldump directly with ssh -i "private.key" user@host mysqldump... -didn't help, it says it can't read the key or something wrong with it, even though it's the same file that I use with Workbench to connect. the version where the database is hosted is 5.7